# .Net Core 6- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, iis, webclient, asp.net-core-3.1, dotnet-httpclient

I have a web api, its calling another api for getting user info.

But sometimes we are getting this timeout error.
[image]
Its happening in QA. not able to reproduce in local.
That third party server is not down. Same time we will get response if we try in postman or curl.

And once this error started coming, either need to restart IIS or apppool. till that, we will get this error.

[image]

Tried HttpClient instead of webclient. tried non-managed code, tried timeout

Any idea ?

Comment: Clearly it *is* down, at least as far as the app is concerned. Either the server is actually down, or the wrong server address, or a firewall or routing issue is blocking it

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, please paste them in as text

Comment: First thing you need to verify is that the URL you are making is correct. Then check in the browser to see if it is browsing. then use Fiddler tool to check what is passing over the network. It may be that URL that is being called through code is wrongly escaped. Then check for firewall related issues.

Comment: @Charlieface third party service is not down. I can call the api via postman or curl and gets response.
and if I make retry from browser after iis reset, will get response. but till iis reset, it will throw error always. 
strange!!

Comment: Compare the two requests in Fiddler, and see if there is a difference, maybe the headers?